# Mysql error while insert ukranian characters

Tags: python, mysql

```
insertDBq(bodyT_uk,8,5*10**8+int(id),vote,i,'ukranian',title)

def insertDBq(body,user_id,post_id,vote,unique_id,language,title):
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="password",database="stack_overflow_v2");
    string='REPLACE INTO posts(body, user_id, id, vote, unique_id, language, title) VALUES'+"('"+str(body)+"',"+'"'+str(user_id)+'","'+str(post_id)+'","'+str(vote)+'","'+str(unique_id)+'","'+str(language)+'","'+str(title)+'");';
    mycursor.execute(string);
    mydb.commit()
    return print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

I do mysql replace query - while all query successfully end for other languages - for example polish, russian, english - it spew sql error for ukranian!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in insertDBq
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 651, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 538, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to
 use near 'яносто і більше років, набагато довше, ніж мÐ' at line 4
>>>
```

**bodyT_uk value below:**

> "
>
> Одним з найбільш часто цитованих фактів про життя людини,
> порівняно з життям інших тварин, є те, що основною причиною того, що
> ми живемо набагато довше, є сучасна медицина. Оскільки ми можемо
> лікувати хвороби, які раніше впливали на тривалість життя, ми маємо
> набагато більше шансів прожити значно продовжений термін життя. Однак
> це призводить до двох можливих [суперечливих] логічних висновків:
>
> \n\n
>
>   \n
> 1. Люди, які випадково не захворіли смертельними
>    хворобами до сучасної медицини, жили б стільки, скільки живуть
>    сьогодні люди, тобто здатність будь-якої  *людини*  вижити
>    дев'яносто і більше років, набагато довше, ніж майже всі тварини , не
>    має відношення до сучасної медицини.
>   \n
> 2. Кожна хвороба, яку
>    людина переживає, певним чином послаблює організм, позбавляючи його
>    майбутніх років. Це означало б, що роль сучасної медицини у
>    продовженні тривалості життя полягає у лікуванні цих хвороб, щоб
>    запобігти поступовому скороченню тривалості життя.
>   \n
>
> \n\n
>
> Якщо перше відповідає дійсності, тоді сама тривалість життя не впливає
> на сучасну медицину, якщо тільки вона не запобігає смерті як
> безпосередній результат захворювання, і це впливає лише на 
> *середню*  тривалість життя. Іншими словами, якщо дев'ятий з десяти
> помирає у віці тридцяти років через смертельну хворобу, а кожен
> десятий помирає у віці вісімдесяти років, уникаючи хвороби, середня
> тривалість життя становить тридцять п'ять, хоча людина, проживаючи
> надзвичайно обережне життя, може вижити досягти вісімдесяти.
>
> \n\n
>
> Якщо друге відповідає дійсності, то короткі періоди
> несмертельних захворювань, які переживають усі, скорочують тривалість
> життя на крихітну суму, разом зменшуючи  *всі*  життя до тих
> самих тридцяти п’яти, ніж ефект є результатом середніх показників.
>
> \n\n
>
> **Тож кожна хвороба скорочує тривалість життя, чи
> це лише результат середніх показників, що тривалість життя була
> настільки низькою, як досучасна медицина, і люди завжди мали здатність
> до надзвичайно довгого життя?**   "

Comment: Sorry i'm confused. Is the non-english the error or part of the question?

Comment: Don't use `+` or any kind of string formatting to create SQL strings. It will make your app vulnerabil to SQL injections and encoding problems. Check the docs on how to give arguments to `execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem not caused by specified language. It caused by wrong approach. You using simple string concatenate, and in your example `дев'яносто` caused to non escaped quote problem.
You must to use parametrized query execution:

```
query="REPLACE INTO posts(body, user_id, id, vote, unique_id, language, title) VALUES ('%s', %d, %d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');"
mycursor.execute(query % (body, user_id, id, vote, unique_id, language, title));
```